# Azure Machine Learning workspace's storage account permission issue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

Was working on az ml cli v2 to deploy real-time endpoint with command `az ml online-deployment` through Azure pipeline. had double confirmed that the service connection used in this pipeline task had added the permissions below in Azure Portal but still showing the same error.

```
ERROR: Error with code: You don't have permission to alter this storage account. Ensure that you have been assigned both Storage Blob Data Reader and Storage Blob Data Contributor roles.
```

Using the same service connection, we are able to perform the creation of online endpoint with `az ml online-endpoint create` in the same and other workspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved. I did not change anything in the service principal and running it on second day using same yml got through the issue. I guess there might be some propagation issue, but longer than usual.